# Filter by JSON values on Doctrine

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have my roles of my users with type json and I would like to get the list of users by roles.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
private $roles = [];
```

```php
$queryBuilder
    ->where("$rootAlias.roles LIKE :role")
    ->setParameter('role', '["ROLE_USER"]')
;
```

This is the error I get:

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown\nLINE 1: ...ce s1_ ON u0_.service_id = s1_.id WHERE u0_.roles LIKE $1 OR...\n
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

It works great like this `"roles"::TEXT LIKE :role` but I don't know how to convert `"roles"::TEXT` in query builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with json, you can use the [DoctrineJsonFunctions](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions) extension.

Installation

```
composer require scienta/doctrine-json-functions
```

Declare a function in **config/packages/doctrine.yaml**

```
orm:
    dql:
        string_functions: 
            JSON_GET_TEXT: Scienta\DoctrineJsonFunctions\Query\AST\Functions\Postgresql\JsonGetText
```

Now you can write such a request in your UserRepository

```
   public function getUsersByRole($role){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->where("JSON_GET_TEXT(u.roles,0) = :role ")
           ->setParameter('role', $role)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works great! I'd tried with `(u.roles, 'role')` but without success. So I'm asking : what does the 0 correspond to?

Comment: The second parameter is needed to specify the key. The value 0 means false since your json has no keys